# How to override public method within Javascript instance

Tags: javascript, dojo

As a newbie in Javascript I have a question regarding public method overriden. It is about Dojo `copyState` method, check the doc [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html).

By default dojo allows copy nodes, but I would like to turn it off, so that i create following Dojo.Dnd object:

```
var order_list = dojo.dnd.Source("order_list");
```

then how to override the public method?

```
dojo.byId("order_list").copyState:function( keyPressed, self ){return false;};
```

seems does not work, FireBug gives:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

dojo.byId("order_list").copyState:function( keyPressed, self ){return false;};
---------------------------------|
```

Comment: do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax seems wrong. It should be like this:

```
dojo.byId("order_list").copyState = function( keyPressed, self ){return false;};
```

Hope that this helps.